# Only take contains string and skip remaining string C#

Tags: c#

i am searching for `searchText` in `someText`. if the `searchText` found in `someText` it is returning the whole `someText`. but i want only `searchText` if found in `someText` and skip the remaining text. hope you understand my question!
if `foundText` is true than it should only `searchText`

```
string someText = "i have Samsung Glaxy";
string searchText = "Samsung Glaxy";

bool foundText = someText.Contains(searchText);
if(foundText)
{
    // here i want only searchText;
    // here found text like this in output
    // Output foundText = "Samsung Glaxy" skip remaining text.
}
```

Comment: `Contains` returns a `bool` (`true` if the searchText was found), not a `string`. What exactly is the problem? Are you looking for `string foundText = someText.Contains(searchText) ? searchText : null;`?

Comment: @RenéVogt `... someText.Contains(searchText) ? someText ...` - _"if the `searchText` found in `someText` it is returning the whole `someText`"_.

Comment: @SᴇM not sure what you mean, my code returns `searchText` if it was found, and that's what OP asked for (_"but I want only `searchText`"_)

Comment: @RenéVogt yeah contains return bool it is my mistake.

Comment: @shahsawar482 Can you give sample inputs and outcomes?

Comment: you have the search text, so if someText contains searchText then you do something with searchText in the if statement. otherwise it doesn't go into the if because that text was not in someText. I think you're overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are just trying to return the string you are searching for, so this would do:

```
string foundText = someText.Contains(searchText) ? searchText : null;
```

Or written in full:

```
string foundText;
if (someText.Contains(searchText))
{
    foundText = searchText;
}
else
{
    foundText = null;
}
```

Comment: _"if the `searchText` found in `someText` it is returning the whole `someText`"_, so it will be `string foundText = someText.Contains(searchText) ? someText : null;`

Comment: It seems you are right @SᴇM

Comment: _"but I want only `searchText`"_ ....seems the question is rather unclear

Comment: @PatrickHofman please see updated question

Comment: I did. Thanks @shahsawar482